# Get a data property value of an individual - OWL API

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, owl-api

I'm trying to get the data property value of my individual from an existing ontology. I'm using OWL API.
For example the name of my inidividual :

```
`
Set<OWLLiteral> literalA = John.getDataPropertyValues(name, ontology);

I've got this error :
> The method getDataPropertyValues(OWLDataPropertyExpression,
> OWLOntology) is undefined for the type OWLIndividua
`
```

This should get me : `"John"`

I've checked on this website the methods I can use to retrieve the information [Interface OWLIndividual](http://soft.vub.ac.be/svn-pub/PlatformKit/platformkit-kb-owlapi3-doc/doc/owlapi3/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLIndividual.html) and it gave me `getDataPropertyValues`. Unfortunately, I can't make it work.

Any idea ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Your Javadoc link is for OWL API version 3.x - which version do you use? It has clearly changed with version [4.x](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLIndividual.html) and [5.x](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLIndividual.html)

Comment: You're right. I'm using the last one 5.x. What method do you suggest to get the info I need ?

Comment: `EntitySearcher` class provides the method you need

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Can you be more precise on what method should I use (with an example), please ?

Comment: EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues(John, name, ontology);

It's a pretty straightforward refactor.

Comment: My bad. it works perfectly. Thank you AKSW and @Ignazio .

Comment: Yeah, I thought looking at the methods of the class `EntitySearcher` should lead you easily to the method you need given that the method name itself is more or less obvious. But ok, Ignazio helped you. Good luck with your project